# Making a jQuery change permanent on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**Back Ground:**

I have made a script that loads a table of product names, when you click a button on that table row it shows a search box. This search box uses the jquery UI autocomplete function. When an option is selected it pulls that products information from a different database from this main project database and puts them in their corresponding

tags within the table. It also then submits this content to another table in another database which is the main database for the project. It is storing the information correctly, and when the foreach loop runs with the database content from the main project it is loading correctly. The button that the user presses to reveal the search box says "Link Product", once they selected it the button changes css and html value to Edit Product.

**The problem**

The issue I'm having is any table row that has content loaded from the main database needs to have the "Edit Button" still be there and any blank rows must show the Link Product Button. But when you refresh the page they all revert to "Link Button".

Now I'm going to show you the code but I will give you a heads up its very messy as I'm new to both ajax and jquery.

**The Code**

Html Page

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <h3 id="edit_sheet_title" class="mt-3 mb-3"><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center">
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>product/import/<?php echo $sheet_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary tb">Bulk Import</a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>container/import/<?php echo $sheet_id; ?>" class="btn btn-info tb">Container Import</a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>product/add/<?php echo $sheet_id; ?>" class="btn btn-warning tb">Add Product</a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>sheet/generate" class="btn btn-success tb">Generate Sheet</a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>" class="btn btn-danger tb">Go Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="table-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table" id="sheet_list">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="align-middle th-id">ID</th>
                            <th class="align-middle th-name">Product Name</th>
                            <th>Ingredients</th>
                            <th id="button_th"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php if(!empty($sheet_product_list)) { ?>
                        <?php foreach($sheet_product_list as $product) { ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td><p data-id="entry_id" id="entry_id" class="table-p"><?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?></p></td>

                                <td class="td-name"><?php echo $product['display_name']; ?></td>

                                <td>
                                    <div id="search_div">
                                        <input type="text" class="wholesale_product_search mb-5 block" data-info="search_box" data-entry-id="<?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?>" name="product_search" id="product_search" placeholder="Search for product...">
                                    </div>

                                    <p data-info="product_id" id="product_id" class="<?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?>">
                                        <?php if(isset($product['wholesale_product_id'])){ echo "Product ID: " . $product['wholesale_product_id'];} ?>  
                                    </p>

                                    <p data-info="wholesale_name" id="wholesale_name" class="<?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?>">
                                        <?php if(isset($product['wholesale_name'])){ echo $product['wholesale_name'];} ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <p data-info="is_manual" class="<?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?>">

                                    </p>
                                    <p data-info="ingredients_section" id="ingredients_section" class="<?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?>">
                                        <?php if(isset($product['wholesale_ingredients'])){echo $product['wholesale_ingredients'];} ?>

                                        </p>
                                </td>

                                <td class="pull-right align-middle">
                                    <div class="button_td_div">
                                        <button id="edit_product_button" data-id="<?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Product</button><br>
                                        <a id="column_button" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>product/delete/<?php echo $sheet['sheet_id']; ?>/<?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete Product</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="sheet_id" value="<?php echo $sheet_id; ?>">
```

Jquery Function

```
$('button[data-id]').click( function () {
    var display_name = $('.td-name').html();
    var entry_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var search_box = $("input[data-info='search_box'][data-entry-id="+entry_id+"]");
    var ingredients_section = $("p[data-info='ingredients_section']."+entry_id);
    var wholesale_name = $("p[data-info='wholesale_name']."+entry_id);
    var wholesale_product_id = $("p[data-info='product_id']."+entry_id);
    var edit_button = $('button[data-id='+entry_id+']');
    const sheet_id = $('#sheet_id').val();

    $(search_box).on( "autocompleteselect", function(e, ui) {
        var result_string = ui.item.value; // this is the string returned from the search
        var product_id = result_string.match( /\d+/ )[0];
        $(search_box).hide();
        edit_button.html('Edit Product');
        edit_button.removeClass("btn btn-warning").addClass("btn btn-success");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ajax_url,
            data: "product_id="+product_id,  
            success: function(data){
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                const ingredients = obj[0].ingredients;
                const product_name = obj[0].name;
                const w_product_id = obj[0].product_id;
                $(wholesale_product_id).html('Product ID: '+w_product_id);
                $('#confirmed').show();
                $(wholesale_name).html('Wholesale Name: '+product_name);
                $(ingredients_section).html(ingredients);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: ajax_url,
                    data: {post_sheet_id: sheet_id,post_wholesale_product_id: w_product_id, post_wholesale_ingredients: ingredients, entry_id: entry_id,wholesale_product_name: product_name},
                    success: function(data){
                        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: ajax_url,
                            data: "sheet_id="+sheet_id+"&content",
                            success: function(data){
                                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                const content = obj[0].wholesale_product_id;
                                console.log(content);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } );
    if($(this).html() == 'Link Product'){
        $(search_box).show();
        $(search_box).focus();
        $(this).html('Cancel');
        $(this).removeClass("btn btn-info");
        $(this).addClass("btn btn-warning");
    } else if($(this).html() == 'Cancel'){
        $(search_box).hide();
        $(this).removeClass("btn btn-warning");
        $(this).addClass("btn btn-info");
        $(this).html('Link Product');
    }

} );


$(function() {
    $(".wholesale_product_search").autocomplete({
        source: ajax_url,
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

I have not a single clue how to make the Edit Product html value to stay on the page refresh, every time I refresh that page all the buttons go back to saying Link Product, but I only want blank ingredients boxes to have a "Link Product" button, any  with ingredients loaded the button needs to say "Edit Product".

I have been driven mad by this for days and I'm at my whits end.

Any help, literally anything at all would spare me my sanity.

** EDIT **

I know its a horrendous mess, but my deadline is fast approaching I'm miles off and at this point will do whatever it takes to make it work. It's used in house and is not accessible to the outside world.

Comment: Help us help you. Can you reduce the code to the bare minimum to reproduce your problem? It does not need to copy the actual problem of you, just the pattern of it.

Comment: I really wish I could, that's the problem I seem to have coded myself into a corner. I don't know how to reduce it. I fear I need it start from scratch, which is a really bad option for me.

Comment: Your exact business requirement isn't that clear, but: if you want the button to say "Edit Product" then you have two choices 1) render it during the php 2) change it via js after load.  You're effectively changing it in js with search action already, so it's the same code just needs to identify when it should change.  However, if you know *when* it should show the Edit button, then it will be much better to make the change in the php when it renders the button (ie: if product has been editted, show "edit" button otherwise show "link" button) (as I understand the requirement))

Comment: I am going to take a different approach instead of an edit button ill make it so the p elements are editable when clicked on and then when blured ajax to save the changes

Answer (score 0):

Just use `php if else` statmant:

```
<?= isset($product['wholesale_ingredients']) ? 'Edit product' : 'Link Product' ?>
```

This will echo '**Edit product**' if `wholesale_ingredients` is set, and '**Link product**' `wholesale_ingredients` is empty

This is how your actual button should look like

```
<div class="button_td_div">
    <button id="edit_product_button" data-id="<?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button">
       <?= isset($product['wholesale_ingredients']) ? 'Edit product' : 'Link Product' ?>
    </button><br>
    <a id="column_button" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>product/delete/<?php echo $sheet['sheet_id']; ?>/<?php echo $product['entry_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete Product</a>
</div>
```